# process builder failing

Tags: process-builder

I have process builder that looks at a custom lookup field on the account object and uses that to assign the related contacts to that user. The logic is that if that custom lookup field is not "unassigned" then the related contact owners are transferred to that user id. If it is "unassigned" then the related contact owners are transferred to the account owner user id.

I am getting hundreds of these flowapplication errors:

> Error element myRule_4_A1 (FlowRecordUpdate). The flow tried to update
>   these records: null. This error occurred:
>   CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:
>   DSCORGPKG.DiscoverOrgCustomMapping_Contact: System.LimitException:
>   Apex CPU time limit exceeded.

I don't know how to fix this or why it is referencing a discoverorg pakage field... nothing like that is even part of the process! Please help! TIA!

Comment: Which object you are updating? That object might have triggers /processbuilder too that runs for managed package

Comment: the process updates the contact owner on the contact object

Comment: I looked at the package components and it is an apex trigger. It is managed though so I cannot deactivate or edit it in any way. Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: Is this happening in like a bulk load or is it happening when updating a single record?

Comment: It happened before in a bulk upload, but I thought it was something else and dismissed it. Now it's happening again, but I am not bulk uploading anything, so it must be getting triggered by some other API connection. I don't even know what's triggering the process to be honest. Is there a way I can find out? Also, I can tell you through testing and production scenarios, this does not happen on single record changes, so something is causing a bulk load.